# Getting an identifier exception when trying to use a static variable in Java

Tags: java, recursion, exception, compiler-errors, static

I am learning recursion and I am trying to create a `reverseString` method without loops. When declaring a variable to be manipulated, I get these two errors:

```
MyClass.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
    int static count = 1;
       ^
MyClass.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
    int static count = 1;
                    ^
2 errors
```

Does anyone know why? Here is my code:

```
public class MyClass {
    int static count = 1;
    public static String reverseString(String str) {
        String reverse = "";
        String sub = str.substring(str.length() - count, str.length() - count + 1);
        reverse += sub;
        if (sub.length() != 1) {
            return reverseString(str.substring(0, str.length() - count));
        } else {
            return reverse;
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(reverseString("Hello"));
    }
}
```

Comment: "*`int static ...`*" -> `static int ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifiers (like `static`) should come before the type:

```
static int count = 1;
```